# Handling TCP connection failure in c++ cassandra client using a thrift wrapper library

Tags: c++, tcp, cassandra, thrift, cql

I am writing a *Cassandra's thrift client wrapper library in c++*. Each of my application threads make connections to several of Cassandra nodes in one data center in a *multiple data center setup*.

I am planning to have a dedicated thread to handle on the fly *TCP connection failures* between application and Cassandra nodes that does the connection retry and switches to other data center when several nodes in one data-center are unreachable. This thread will be informed about connection failures by application threads.

My question is : How should this process/thread work? Is there any thrift call or CQL query that can tell the current up/down nodes in data center(like the nodetool does) or I need to retry making connection and run dummy queries to every down node to check ?

Comment: Have you checked the existing high-level Cassandra clients? Writing one from scratch requires certain knowledge about Cassandra internals. It's not to say, that it can't be done, but there are already a bunch of them which are certainly more well-tested.

Comment: I understand that it is tough to write it from scratch, thats why I've modelled my library mostly around Hector client written in Java and libQtCassandra in c++ and adapting them to meet our requirements. Rest of the part of my library is working fine now, its just this bit that I want to explore and see if there's a better way of doing it.

Comment: There is a native driver for C++ in beta at https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver